# SharePoint 2010 Site bandwidth Usage

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I want to obtain a bandwidth utilization report for a Site Collection. Can any one let me know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box.

You could get the utilized bandwidth from the iis logs but you need to create a parser. Group by the url of the sites from the log and sum the bytes transfered =>  rough bandwidth per site. 
You have to do this on every web frontend.